# Как обрезать файл C++

Tags: c++, файлы, файловая-система

Я имею текстовый файл, ассоциированный с объектом `std::fstream`.

```
std::fstream finout("text.txt");
```

Затем из этого файла производиться чтение. Считанные данные анализируются и некоторые из них удаляются. Таким образом размер выходных данных может уменьшиться и возникает необходимость усечь файл (либо же изменить его размер). Кажется совершенно глупо и расточительно создавать новый файл и записывать результат в него. Мне хотелось бы получить более эффективный и простой способ добиться желаемого результата. Язык Си предлагает функции `ftruncate` и `chsize`, однако я использую объект класса `std::fstream`.

P. S. На англоязычных сайтах я встречал подобные вопросы, но мне хотелось бы узнать мнение русскоязычной аудитории.

Comment: связанные вопросы: [How to truncate a file while it is open with fstream](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20809113/4279) и [How to truncate a file in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/873454/4279)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fstream` не поддерживает подобных операций.

Можете попробовать использовать `std::experimental::filesystem::resize_file` (c++17)

Ну или старые добрые `_chsize/ftruncate`.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос неправильно поставлен - если данные в файле удаляются произвольно, в любой месте - какое тут может быть обрезание?? Формировать файл заново а старый удалять.
Однако если это ну ооочень большой файл и переформировать его нерационально - можно использовать [seekp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/seekp/) - в этом случае можно придумать какую-то структуру файла, чтобы помечать удаляемые куски как пустые, затем при пополнении данных искать подходящего размера пустые куски и записывать туда - хоть в начала, в середине, в конце файла...